# How to refresh image from camera in background without refreshing whole page?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, refresh

I am using PHP script (currentimage.php) to get a snapshot from my CCTV IP camera, which works fine:

```
<?php
while (@ob_end_clean()); 
    header('Content-type: image/jpeg'); 
// create curl resource 
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://192.168.0.20/Streaming/channels/1/picture'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'username:password'); 
// $output contains the output string 
$output = curl_exec($ch); 
echo $output; 
// close curl resource to free up system resources 
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

and another PHP/HTML to display the data:

```
<IMG id="myImage" SRC='currentimage.php'>
```

but I can't get it to work to refresh the image in background every 30s.
I am trying AJAX, but no success:

```
<script>
      function refresh_image(){
          document.getElementbyId("myImage").setAttribute("src", "currentimage.php");
        }
        setInterval(function(){refresh_image()}, 30000);
</script>
```

What I am doing wrong? I will appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the concept of changing the displayed image via timed requests to a PHP script, and it works fine. A new request is fired up to the image getting script if the URL is modified, and I did so by appending a version number as a parameter to the URL.

```js
var version = 1;
function refresh_image(){
  document.getElementById("myImage").setAttribute("src", "currentimage.php?ver="+version);
  version++;
}

setInterval(function(){
  refresh_image();
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score -1):

I suspect the main problem here is that the browser caches your file and will not reload it if you set the attribute again. I've found a way around this though:

```
document.getElementbyId("myImage").setAttribute("src", "currentimage.php?version=1");
```

Save the version number and count up every time you make the request. This way, the browser will treat it as a new URL and it will be reloaded again (check this using the developer functions of your browser in the network tab).